# What do we do with homework-like questions?

Tags: discussion

Title's pretty clear on what i'm asking.  But what should we do with questions like these:

- [A Practical Guide to Ubuntu Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281087/a-practical-guide-to-ubuntu-linux)
- [Ubuntu Linux install xeyes command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281097/ubuntu-linux-install-xeyes-command)

... which rely on getting an answer to complete what looks like a homework assignment, as well as are dependent on a paid-for text book which is likely looking for a specific answer that we may or may not be able to give here?

Comment: It's probably a first for Ask Ubuntu. Very bizarre to face homework sort of questions on a site which deals with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The thing with home work question is that most of the time they have been answered before.

To me ...

- the 1st one is already marked a dupe so it will be gone soon.
- the 2nd one is not even a valid question on AU. It is not a question but an assignment.

AU has this in the FAQ:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Emphasis on *actual*.

Comment: Since this and the other answer both have +10, which counts as a significant number of people and votes, I've marked this answer here as accepted.  To the mods: It may be prudent to modify the FAQ to say "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.  Homework problems, and similar questions, do not fall within the scope of this site."

Comment: @TheLordofTime hmmm those 10 upvoting me are more than likely 9 times the same person that upvoted call me v. Plus he upvoted me and I upvoted him.

Comment: Well, there's two answers saying pretty much the same thing, so... :/

Answer (score 25):

My vote is we post this as an answer:
[image]
Of course I'm kidding, but I couldn't help myself...

Comment: Heheh, that was pretty epic a post.  Nice.