# Why this question is off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Why this question: [Script Bash - Comparison on two directories [on hold]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546159/script-bash-comparison-on-two-directories) is off-topic? It is a question on bash. Rather it may be a duplicate of [Script Bash - Comparison on two directories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546408/bash-script-operations-on-two-directories)

There are plenty of question like this one that are not off-topic, for example: [How can I delete numbered files in a given range?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529270/how-can-i-delete-numbered-files-in-a-given-range)

So, is this a mistake? If not, which kind of question about bash are off-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not "off-topic" but it isn't a good question either, Voters should have selected "Too Broad" as Seth said on the other question https://askubuntu.com/questions/546408/bash-script-operations-on-two-directories#comment748771_546408

The too broad wording:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Also any answer would need to code for the person from scratch, we are not a coding service.

Also the wording of his request, leads us to believe that he copy and pasted a homework assignment, and we won't do his homework for him either. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6520/what-do-we-do-with-homework-like-questions So, I'm willing just to leave those questions closed like they are since they are terrible anyway, and unless a mod wants to fix the reason it would be counterproductive to try and reopen a question that should be closed anyway.

And we don't vote to close as duplicates to things that are already closed.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you, these questions are terrible, and I'm not asking to reopen them, I did not understand the choice of off-topic. So, now I'm learning that no matter why they are closed, but it is important that bad questions are closed :)